# MicrosoftGraph querying for @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl returns character '@' is not valid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have problem querying for "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" using microsoft graph endpoint.
Running a query like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$select=id,name,file,folder,size,lastModifiedDateTime,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
```

Returns a bad request error with message: "Syntax error: character '@' is not valid at position..." I had not such a problem with OneDrive direct endpoint so I am wondering how exactly should I run the intended query?

Answer (score 12):

Earlier this year the attribute `@content.downloadUrl` was renamed to `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`.It looks like there is an issue/discrepancy between the attribute's name in the results verse the query parameters.

The `$select` clause is still looking for the original name. As best I can tell, this isn't documented at the moment. That said, this query should do the trick for you:

`/me/drive/root/children?$select=id,name,file,folder,size,lastModifiedDateTime,content.downloadUrl`

Comment: Thanks, although this works for web api, strangely, I its not working for .Net library!

Comment: There are some nuances around downloading files using the .Net SDK. There is an example/walkthrough available at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/8118937320e68ece7d6143aaed3da887531495ff/docs/readme.md

Comment: Indeed. The problem is that I can get "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" instance attribute while not filtering the request. But in my case since I am fetching list of files, there will be relatively large overhead of redundant data.

Comment: Are you looking to grab a large list of download links? This isn't a good idea since this links are very short-lived. You're better off grabbing a filtered list of files that have a downloadUrl and then pulling the actual URL only when the user wants to download the actual file.

Comment: As of June 20, 2018, using the old name `@content.downloadUrl` to select the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` field is still working, and apparently the only way to do it.

Comment: Still this is a bug in 2020!!

Comment: Late 2021 here, I can confirm this still works! :)

Comment: @chrisfrancis27 what URL did you use? this doesn't show the downloadUrl for me with web api (postman)
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$select=id,name,file,folder,size,lastModifiedDateTime,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl

Comment: @JamesH In the `$select` query you need to use `content.downloadUrl` instead of `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`. When the response comes back, however, it'll be in a field called `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`. In your case this would be https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$select=id,name,file,folder,size,lastModifiedDateTime,content.downloadUrl - hope this helps!

Comment: @chrisfrancis27 thanks but I ran your link it only gives all the specified properties except for download URL. It's weird not sure what I did wrong. If I remove the $select, it shows all properties including download URL without issue.

Comment: @JamesH Hmm, that's strange. I'm actually not using the `/me/drive` endpoint, I'm hitting a Sharepoint site instead but it should be the same. Here's my URL for posterity (IDs obfuscated): `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site-id>/drives/<drive-id>/items/<item-id>/children?$select=id,name,folder,file,image,size,content.downloadUrl&$expand=thumbnails($select=medium)&$top=100`

Comment: 2022 and this name discrepancy still exists

Comment: As of December 9, 2022, you still need to use the old name ...

Comment: as of 12 May 2023 you still have to use the old name. MS need to document this somewhere obvious to stop all of us wasting an hour trying to see why it does not work as advertised.

Comment: Just here to update all of you, this is still happening in 30 May 2023 :D . At least SO has better doc than the official microsoft one

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case, you can now use @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl in your select clause, for example https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?select=name,folder,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl

Comment: @UnionP Unfortunately it still does not work for me for a Sharepoint for Business site.